# How to set a layout once a matplotlib Figure has been created and what are the possible choices?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say that I created a *Figure* with

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
```

and then AFTER I created I want to change its *layout* (I am aware that I can instantiate the *Figure* object by passing the argument *layout* to *plt.figure*, e.g. `fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")`, which is not what I want).

So far, I know that one could do

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

to set a tight layout, but what if one to set a *"constrained"* layout?

Furthermore, other than *"tight"* and *"constrained"* what are the other possible available layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fig.set_layout_engine()` with `matplolib-3.6.2` :

As follows:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_layout_engine('constrained')
```

The possible layouts as per documentation are: `'constrained', 'compressed', 'tight'`.